# How do I pull photos from my dead phone?

Tags: android

Here is my situation, my phone won't turn on, I can get it to show the start up image and then it resets. I can get it into the boot options and it shows Battery OK and transfer mode: USB connected. I have a Droid mini, this is about as far as I can get with the phone. In linux via terminal It shows up under listed usb devices when I do "lsusb" my question is how do I go about mounting this usb device and pulling the photos.

Comment: do you have a file manager? it will probably show up there and you just click on it.

Comment: Just open files and it will be in the side bar.

Comment: It doesn't show up in files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it won't show up on the command line but it should show up in nautilus or thunar in Ubuntu versions >=14.04. However, you may need to install some MTP stuff before Ubuntu will recognize the device.

First run the following commands to install a few libraries and packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends mtpfs jmtpfs libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
```

Next, plug the device in to the USB port, reboot, and then open up nautilus or thunar and the device should be listed on the left amongst your extra partitions and other external devices.